# Visual Studio/Visio C# New Project helloWorld

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visio, new-project

I am trying to create a new Visual Studio project to do Visio Automation. Code examples on the internet provide .cs code, but do not explain how to setup a new Visual Studio project to use this code.

If I create a new project in Visual Studio 2013 (File -> New -> Project -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Office/SharePoint -> Office Add-ins -> Visio 2013 Add-in), I get a ThisAddIn.cs file of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace VisioAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
}
```

However, examples on the web often take the following form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IVisio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

namespace DemoCurrying
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        static void setfill1(IVisio.Shape shape)
        {
        }
}
```

How must I create a Visio Studio project to run this code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a C# Console Application template Project:

```
 Visual Studio 2013 File -> New -> Project -> C# Console Application
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out a newbie, I have been banging my head against this for last several hours.